# Is this an accepted/valid clustering evaluation metric?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, cluster

We have a clustering algorithm where the number of clusters isn't known to the algorithm - it iteratively creates clusters out of similar-looking data points.

The evaluation metric we're currently using is:

```
for each pair of elements in the dataset:
    if both elements belong to the same class:
        if both are in the same cluster:
            truePositive++
        else:
            falseNegative++ 
     else: // elements belong to different classes
        if both are in same cluster:
            falsePositive++
        else:
            trueNegative++
```

Is this a good/valid evaluation metric? Please note that the number of predicted clusters are usually more than the number of classes/natural clusters in the dataset, and hence can't usually map a cluster to a class label. What other metrics might be suitable in this case?

Comment: What do you think?  Where did this metric come from?  What is your motivation for it?  What research have you done?  I would have thought of something different (e.g., taking a majority vote over the labels of all the elements in a cluster to label each cluster, then measuring how often this label is right/wrong, added to some regularity term that increases with the number of clusters to penalize having too many clusters), but I'm sure this problem must have been studied before.

Comment: Just found out the source I probably got the idea from - http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-clustering-1.html (Read from the section "An alternative to this information-theoretic ... ")

Comment: OK.  Cool, good find!  Does that answer your question, or do you still have a question?  If it answers your question, I suggest you write an answer to your own question, based on what you found there.  If it doesn't answer your question, I suggest you edit your question to include this citation to the metric and the standard name for this metric, and the intuition behind the justification given there, and then edit the question to ask a more focused question, based on what you've learned from that source.